# Encontrar max y min en Javascript sin usar array

Tags: javascript

Necesito encontrar el máximo y el mínimo de una secuencia de números que ingresa el usuario, al azar, hasta que el quiere. Es decir, podrían ser 2 números como 356, si así lo quiere.

Sólo puedo utilizar while e if, y no for.

Hasta ahora tengo esto:

```js
  var seguir;
 var numero;
 var maximo;
 var minimo;

 do {
  numero = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese numero"));
  while (isNaN(numero)) {
   numero = parseInt(prompt("Error. Ingrese numero"));
  }
  if (numero < minimo) {
   minimo = numero;
  }
  if (numero > maximo){

   maximo = numero;
  }

  seguir = confirm("Desea continuar?");
 }

 while (seguir);
  
  console.log("max: " + maximo + " Minimo: " + minimo)
```

Pero sólo muestra `undefined`.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola Bornlivedie. bienvenido. te he editado el codigo para que sea ejecutable y se pueda probar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He cambiado tu `Do While` por un `While`  y he inicializado `seguir` a `true` y las variables de numero maximo y minimo al minimo y maximo valor posible respectivamente

```js
var seguir = true;
 var numero;
 var maximo = Number.MIN_VALUE;
 var minimo = Number.MAX_VALUE;


 while (seguir){
  
  numero = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese numero"));
  while (isNaN(numero)) {
   numero = parseInt(prompt("Error. Ingrese numero"));
  }
  if (numero < minimo) {
   minimo = numero;
  }
  if (numero > maximo){

   maximo = numero;
  }

  seguir = confirm("Desea continuar?");
 }

  console.log("max: " + maximo + " Minimo: " + minimo)
```

Comment: Hola, ese codigo me da el maximo pero me muestra 0 en minimo.

Comment: @bornlivedie ah cierto.ahora no puedo, estoy desde el móvil, luego te lo edito. puedes inicializar mínimo con el máximo valor de `int` posible

Comment: Buenas @bornlivedie he añadido el `Number.MAX_VALUE` y `Number.MIN_VALUE`

Comment: Excelente, lois6b. Creo que es la respuesta que buscaba. Muchas gracias!

Comment: @bornlivedie si esta respuesta ayudó a solucionar el problema de tu pregunta, por favor considera [aceptarla](/help/accepted-answer) haciendo click en el **✔️**, que está bajo las flechas de votación, a la izquierda de la misma (no se te descuenta nada por eso -todo lo contrario, ambos se benefician).

Answer (score 0):

Deberias inicializar el minimo con un numero muy grande porque si lo inicias con cero a menos que pongan un numero negativo siempre el minimo será cero

Comment: Si, se que asi funciona, pero la pregunta es, se puede hacer sin inicializarlo en un numero muy grande? Ya que no sabremos que numero se le ocurrira poner al usuario.

Comment: Hola @JudithPalacios. Bienvenida a [es.so]. ¿Podrías mostrar el código que responde a la pregunta? La idea es sumar respuestas de calidad en el sitio y, para alguien que recién está iniciándose, un pequeño fragmento de código puede hacer toda la diferencia.

Comment: no lo puse porque seria repetir el codigo que ya habia compartido @lois6b pero seria var maximo = 0;
 var minimo = 2147483647;